# How can I loop through all <th> tags within my script for web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As of now, I'm only getting `['1']` as the output of what's being printed with my current code below.  I want to grab 1-54 on the Team Batting table in the `Rk` column on the website https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/2019.shtml.

How would I go about modifying `colNum` so it can print the 1-54 in the `Rk` column?  I'm pointing out the `colNum` line because I feel the issue lies there but I could be wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/2019.shtml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  # parse as HTML page, this is the source code of the page
week = soup.find(class_='table_outer_container')

items = week.find("thead").get_text() # grabs table headers
th = week.find("th").get_text() # grabs Rk only.

tbody = week.find("tbody")
tr = tbody.find("tr")

thtwo = tr.find("th").get_text()
colNum = [thtwo for thtwo in thtwo]
print(colNum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was in the last few lines as you mentioned. If I understood right, you wanted a list of all the values in the "Rk" column. In order to get all the rows, you have to use the `find_all()` function. I tweaked your code a little bit in order to get the text of the first field in each row in the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/2019.shtml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
is the source code of the page
week = soup.find(class_='table_outer_container')

items = week.find("thead").get_text()
th = week.find("th").get_text()

tbody = week.find("tbody")
tr = tbody.find_all("tr")
colnum = [row.find("th").get_text() for row in tr]

print(colnum)
```